# Getting weird values while calculating distance from GPS - C

Tags: c, math, gps, type-conversion

I'm calculating total distance travelled by a vehicle using latitude and longitude from GPS in PIC Microcontroller. Here my GPS module is in idle state(not moving), so the total distance should show '0'(zero), yes it's showing zero. But sometimes it shows weird value "9223372036854775808.775808", later my total distance comes to zero.

here is my code;

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <string.h>
#define COMMA 0x2C
#define MAXSIZE 100
#define pi 3.14159265358979323846
double deg2rad(double);
double rad2deg(double);
float stof(char* s);
float Nmea_Degree(char *data);
double dist;
double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit);
float old_lat=0;
float old_lon=0;
float new_lat=0;
float new_lon=0;
int flag=0;
double theta, dist=0,old_dist=0;
int main()
{

    /* Get lattitude */
    int k=0,j=0;
    unsigned  char lastCommaPosition;
    unsigned char stringRead[MAXSIZE]="$GPRMC,124130.000,A,1300.4147,N,08015.4269,E,0.13,224.13,151015,,,D*6A";
    //$GPRMC,124130.000,A,1300.4147,N,08015.4269,E,0.13,224.13,151015,,,D*6A
    //$GPGGA,1300.80,4548.32609,N,01557.99352,E,1,07,1.30,129.1,M,41.4,M,,*5E
    unsigned char *pChar;
    unsigned char latitudeCardinalString[3];
    unsigned char latitudeString[11];
    unsigned char longitudeString[12];
    float longitude;
    float latitude;
    if(strstr(stringRead,"GPRMC")) //if(strstr(nmea,"GPRMC"))
    {
    pChar = stringRead;
    lastCommaPosition = j;
    j = lastCommaPosition + 1;
    while(*(pChar+j) != COMMA)
    {
    latitudeString[k] = *(pChar+j);
    j++;
    k++;
    }
    j=19;
    k=18;
    lastCommaPosition = j; 
    latitudeString[k] = '\0'; 
    sscanf(latitudeString, "%f", &latitude);
    pChar = stringRead;
    j = lastCommaPosition + 1;
    k = 0;
    while(*(pChar+j) != COMMA) {
    latitudeCardinalString[k] = *(pChar+j);
    j++;
    k++;
    }
    lastCommaPosition = j;
    latitudeCardinalString[k] = '\0';
    printf("Latitude(f):%f",Nmea_Degree(latitudeCardinalString)); ////Latitude
    printf("\n");

    new_lat=Nmea_Degree(latitudeCardinalString);
    /* Get Longitude */
    pChar = stringRead;
    j = lastCommaPosition + 1;
    k = 0;
    j=32;
    while(*(pChar+j) != COMMA) {
    longitudeString[k] = *(pChar+j);
    j++;
    k++;
    }

    lastCommaPosition = j;
    longitudeString[k] = '\0';
    sscanf(longitudeString, "%f", &longitude);
    printf("Longitude(f):%f",Nmea_Degree(longitudeString));  ////Longitude
    printf("\n");

    /*extract UTC time*/
        pChar=gpsdata;
        j = 1;  /* start of time field */
        k = 0;
        while(*(pChar+j) != COMMA)
        {
        timeString[k] = *(pChar+j);
        j++;
        k++;
        }
        lastCommaPosition = j;
        timeString[k] = '\0';
        sscanf(timeString, "%ld", &utcTime);
        utcHour = (utcTime/10000);   /* extract Hours from long */
        utcMinutes = (utcTime - (utcHour*10000))/100;  /* extract minutes from long */
        utcSeconds = utcTime - (utcHour*10000) - (utcMinutes*100); /* extract seconds from long */
        if(utcHour >= 4 && utcHour <= 23) estHour = utcHour + 5;
        else estHour = utcHour + 20;
        estMinutes = utcMinutes;
        estSeconds = utcSeconds;

    /*Total distance calculation*/  

    if(utcSeconds==15 || utcSeconds==30 || utcSeconds==45 || utcSeconds==00)
    {

    if(flag==0)
    {
        old_lat=Nmea_Degree(latitudeCardinalString);
        old_lon=Nmea_Degree(longitudeString);
        flag=1;
    }
    else
    {
        new_lat=Nmea_Degree(latitudeCardinalString);
        new_lon=Nmea_Degree(longitudeString);

        printf("%f",distance(old_lat,old_lon,new_lat,new_lon,'N'));
        old_lat=new_lat;
        old_lon=new_lon;
    }


    }
    else
    {

        printf("Bad GPS");
    }
    return 0;
}

float stof(char* s)
{
    int point_seen;
    float rez = 0, fact = 1;
    if (*s == '-')
    {
        s++;
        fact = -1;
    }
    for (point_seen = 0; *s; s++)
    {
        if (*s == '.')
        {
        point_seen = 1;
        continue;
        }
        int d = *s - '0';
        if (d >= 0 && d <= 9)
        {
        if (point_seen) fact /= 10.0f;
        rez = rez * 10.0f + (float)d;
        }
    }
    return rez * fact;
}

float Nmea_Degree(char *data)
{
    double  Value;
    int Degree;
    double  minute;
    Degree=stof(data)/100;
    minute=(float)stof(data)-(100*Degree);
    Value = Degree+(minute/60);
    return Value;
}

double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit) {
  //double theta, dist;
  theta = lon1 - lon2;
  dist = sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * cos(deg2rad(theta));
  dist = acos(dist);
  dist = rad2deg(dist);
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  dist+=dist;
 return (dist);
}

double deg2rad(double deg) {
      return (deg * pi / 180);
    }

    double rad2deg(double rad) {
          return (rad * 180 / pi);
    }
```

Here is the weird value:

```
    Latitude:13.006949
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006949
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006949
Longitude:80.257065
interval:    02
old_lat:13.006952    old_lon:80.257065   new_lat:13.006949   new_lon:80.257065Total distance: 0.000000
Latitude:13.006949
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006949
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006949
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006949
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006949
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006949
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006949
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006949
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006949
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006948
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006948
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006948
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006948
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006948
Longitude:80.257065
Latitude:13.006948
Longitude:80.257065
old_lat:13.006949    old_lon:80.257065   new_lat:13.006948   new_lon:80.257065Total distance: 9223372036854775808.775808
```

here im passing my gps uart values in stringRead variable.
what is the problem?

Thanks...

Comment: First of all, please fix the formatting of your code. It's unreadable.
And secondly, GPS is not perfect, there may be some deviations and precision errors here and there. But I expect a software error on your part, due to the size of that travelled distance number.

Comment: Switch on compiler warnings and clean them.

Comment: Note PIC does not provide `__STDC_IEC_559__`.

Comment: You seem to have an sever error: either initialisation is wrong, or something worse. The maximum distance between two GPS coordinates is not more than 40.000 km earth circum fence). It is a common error to calcuate the distance to the intials (0.0, 0.0). However in your case there is something worse. Such extreme values show an error, not caused by GPS.

Comment: Just print out the lat/long coordinates of the two location you want to calculate the distance for.

Comment: It is certainly no coincidence that `9223372036854775808` is `0xCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC`.   Post the code that prints "old_lat:13.006949    old_lon:80.257065   new_lat:13.006948   new_lon:80.257065Total distance: 9223372036854775808.775808".  Possible that the issue is not in posted code.